# Why does resulting code differ, from two ways of declaring a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

Apologies if this has been asked before; I find it difficult to come up with appropriate search terms.

Why is:

```
public class IsUserAnonymousCondition<T> : WhenCondition<T> where T: RuleContext
{
    protected override bool Execute( T ruleContext )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

different from:

```
public class IsUserAnonymousCondition : WhenCondition<RuleContext>
{
    protected override bool Execute( RuleContext ruleContext )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or rather; do these two not compile to be the excact same?   And if not, why not?

They both compile and therefore should both override the same base method.

```
public abstract class WhenCondition<T> : RuleCondition<T> where T : RuleContext
{
  protected abstract bool Execute(T ruleContext);
}
```

Comment: Actually, the second class is *not* generic, unlike the first one.

Comment: While in your example, the classes may behave the same way in runtime, you have to realize that generics give you a lot of *compile time* benefits. You can try to make your types as generic as possible using the most abstract types or even `object` but from API perspective it's a horrible experience. There's also the boxing/unboxing issue for reference and value types...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more practical terms, they are not synonymous in your case due to:

```
class StrinctRuleContext : RuleContext {}
```

Have a subclass.  we can then have

```
var aStrinctRuleContext = new StrinctRuleContext();
var aRulesContext = new RuleContext();
```

whence I can have

`new IsUserAnonymousCondition<StrinctRuleContext>().Execute(aRulesContext)` which is a compile error, ie the generic version allows a *STRICTER* type restriction on its inputs than the non-generic version. ie I am free to make a IsUserAnonymousCondition than cannot 'cope' with the base RulesContext class.

the generic version also keeps the ability to add further generic restrictions if it is futher subclassed, ie:

```
IsUserAnonymousConditionThatNeedsSomeExtraMojo : IsUserAnonymousCondition<T> where T : ISomeExtraMojo
```

which of couse actualising the type to RuleContext does not.

Comment: This makes sense. I was too focused on just the current scenario, and how the 2 variations (in my mind) would essentially compile to the same thing. Of course they do not, I see that now :-)

Answer (score 1):

The two classes provide the same interface, but the simple fact that one class is generic and the other one is not lead to some significant differences.

The most obvious way to see how the two are different would be to try instantiating them from a class name using reflection: in the first case you would have to obtain a generic class by name, make a type representing a generic type instance with `RuleContext` as its type parameter, and only then create an instance of it. In the second case a name alone would be sufficient to obtain the type.

A more subtle issue is that the types of `IsUserAnonymousCondition<RuleCtx1>` and `IsUserAnonymousCondition<RuleCtx2>` instantiated with two different types would be different. This implies that you wouldn't be able to put different `IsUserAnonymousCondition<T>` objects into a non-generic container.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same - though in your case there is no functional difference because `T` is only use as an input.

The difference would be if  `WhenCondition<T>` has a method that used `T` as an *output*:

```
public abstract class WhenCondition<T> : RuleCondition<T> where T : RuleContext
{
  protected abstract bool Execute(T ruleContext);
  protected abstract T GetContext();
}
```

Now your two classes would be different, since the *actual* return type of `IsUserAnonymousCondition.GetContext()` would not be known at design time (the compiler just knows it derives from `RuleContext`), but the return type of  `IsUserAnonymousCondition<T>.GetContext()` would be known.

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

```
WhenCondition<T> where T: RuleContext
```

`T` is *or* derives from `RuleContext`. The actual type is not known at compile time.

Here it is:

```
WhenCondition<RuleContext>
```

It doesn't matter a lot now, but think what the difference will be when doing this:

```
T GetSomething()
```

vs.

```
RuleContext GetSomething()
```

The return type of the first can be different from the second one.